# Suggest best approach for an Angular Chat

Tags: ajax, angularjs, database, laravel-5, web-chat

I am developing a Web Based chat system. Using angularjs in the front end. It will be developed using simple `PULL` requests (or AJAX call to the server).
The back-end is being developed using Laravel 5.

**The scenario**:
The chat has 2 sections - the upper section shows all the 'chats' sequentially. In the lower end has a input field and a send button.
An API is responsible to PUT data into the server database. So whenever the users type in and hit 'Send' - their texts will be added onto the server.

**The question**:
What is the best way to show the series of messages in the upper section? Shall I create 2 distinct Controllers to bind these 2 sections? Doing so will send the 'Text Data' to server **first** . The upper section will keep making asynchronous calls at definite intervals to pull data from the server and show. This way 2 controllers can work independently.

Or when an user types in hit send - it will be shown in the list first and then send it to the server ?

Please suggest.

For specific reasons this project does not use real time service like FIREBASE, instead it will use complete custom APIs to send and receive messages from the server.